# Why does AsyncStorage takes long time to load the data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am creating a simple calculator application in react native, and I am using AsyncStorage for storing results, but it takes too long to get the data from AsyncStorage.

Comment: Why you're using asyncStorage?

Comment: Use SSD then....

Comment: @LouaySleman I'm using it to to store the previous results. but it takes too long to  load data from asyncStorage.

Comment: If you want them instantly then use store/Redux I'll write an answer

Comment: @LouaySleman the solution worked, but i wanna know the reason why asyncStorage is too slow...

Comment: Async Storage It's an async function it takes time to get data from your shared-Preferences  and save them into your variable and then you can use them the time will be difference from device to device depends on specifications.

Comment: AsyncStorage takes about 12x more time to read/write on average compared to localStorage you can read more about from here https://medium.com/@Sendbird/extreme-optimization-of-asyncstorage-in-react-native-b2a1e0107b34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

If you want to get the data instantly then you can store the data in a store provider like `Redux` and you can store it in your async storage so you can reach them back if the app closed.

```
saveDataAction: (payload) => dispatch(saveDataAction(payload))
```

**Solution 2**

If you don't care about using the data in multiple pages then you can use useState to store data and get it instantly.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);



const getData = () => {
   fetch(url).then(data => setData(data));
}
```